# Inner join pandas df (python) and sql db

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Currently, I'm performing data analysis in a big SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy. I have managed to create a Pandas DataFrame that I like and would like to inner join this data with another database in SQL.

To keep things simple, my DataFrame looks like this:

| Advertise_ID | Client_ID | Running_Since | Running_Until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-05-15 |
| 2 | 50 | 2023-05-05 | 2023-05-20 |
| 3 | 60 | 2023-05-10 | 2023-05-25 |

So I need to get the clients' transactions for their respective date ranges. In SQL, it would look something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table_a AS a INNER JOIN table_b AS b ON a.Client_ID = b.Client_ID AND b.Transaction_Date BETWEEN a.Running_Since AND a.Running_Until`

I'm currently uploading my Pandas DataFrame as a temp table and then performing the inner join using SQLAlchemy to retrieve the data again, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this. Perhaps doing an inner join directly from Python instead of uploading it to SQL.

Also, I tried to get all transactional data between the first "Running Since" and "Running Until" dates, but there are over 1 million rows each with different date ranges. Adding all transactions for each one takes over 40 minutes to query, which is not optimal.

Comment: Why do you do it with pandas and not with the database query language ? Moreover, for "big" data processing, big data tools are more likely to help you.

Comment: I have a better understading of python atm, and I'm not sure I can achieve what I'm doing there in sql server 2008.